# MVC 3 issues with one route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im having one issue with one route:

This is my global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute("TagsHome", "belleza-y-{tagnameurl}/", new { controller = "Tag", action = "Detail" });

routes.MapRoute("CategoryHome", "{categorynameurl}/", new { controller = "Categories", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute("HomePage", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

My problem is that when i debug the project on `http://localhost:4097/` the route that MVC is using is this:

```
routes.MapRoute("CategoryHome", "{categorynameurl}/", new { controller = "Categories", action = "Index" });
```

but should use the one for the home page:

```
 routes.MapRoute("HomePage", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Do you know why it is selecting this route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i solved the problem adding a constraint for categorynameurl parameter:

```
routes.MapRoute("CategoryHome", "{categorynameurl}/", new { controller = "Categories", action = "Index" },new {categorynameurl = @"[a-z0-9\-]+$" });
```

Answer (score 3):

Routes are Selected in the order they are added.

Move your Homepage route above the CategoryHome route.

you can use this Routing Debugger tool by Phill Haack if you have problems your routes again:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

another route debugger exists in Glimpse. a really nice plugin you should try: http://getglimpse.com/

Answer (score 1):

Matching routes are selected in the order they appear.

Move

`routes.MapRoute("HomePage", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });`

up so it is above

`routes.MapRoute("CategoryHome", "{categorynameurl}/", new { controller = "Categories", action = "Index" });`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right to me. Unless you have specified your {categorynameurl} parameter as optional or a wildcard it should not match the route.

Take the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return Content("index");
    }

    public ActionResult Foo(string foo) {
        return Content("foo");
    }
}
```

And the following route configuration:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute("", "{foo}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Foo" });
        routes.MapRoute("", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "index" });
    }
```

`http://localhost/` is matched by our empty url route -> Home/Index
`http://localhost/abc123` is matched by our foo route -> Home/Foo

@geertvdc has mentioned some good tools for debugging routes. You should also test them. I wrote a post about testing both inbound route matching and outbound url generation [here](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/ASPNET-MVC-Outbound-Url-tests-with-NSubstitute.aspx).